# search in datagridview C# winfom

Tags: c#, winforms, search, datagridview

I want to put a search option in `DataGridView`, i.e., User types the string or int in `TextBox` and similar records the `DataGridView` should be highlighted. I tried it using `KeyPress` event but didn't work.

```
  if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < (dgemployee.Rows.Count); i++)
     {
         if (dgemployee.Rows[i].Cells["Employee"].Value.ToString().
                    StartsWith(e.KeyChar.ToString(), true, 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
         {
             dgemployee.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = true;
             return;                     
         }
      }
```

Actually, I need to search the whole `DataGridView`, not only one column and row. So any best solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your DataGridView is bound to a DataTable or a DataView, you can do this:

Create a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx) and make `BindingSource.DataSource` the Datatable or DataView that your DGV is currently using.  Then set your `DataGridView.DataSource` to the BindingSource.  Then you can use the `BindingSource.Filter` property to query your datasource by setting the `BindingSource.Filter`to your query string which will automatically filter the DGV.  You can find the syntax [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) - it is very similar to basic SQL queries, except you can only use wild cards on the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: thanks for this comment Now I can efficiently filter my dgview :) great job

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DataView.RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) property.

Also take a look at [DataTable.DefaultView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx)

Take a look at [this article](http://techbystep.blogspot.com/2009/07/dynamic-searchingfiltering-of.html) I wrote some time back on filtering data real time.

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void txtsearchgroup_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        SqlConnection objconnection = new SqlConnection(servername and ...);
        DataView Dv = new DataView();
        objcommand = new SqlCommand("select name from groupitems", objconnection);
        objdataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        objdataadapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
        objdataadapter.SelectCommand = objcommand;
        objdataset = new DataSet();
        objconnection.Open();
        objdataadapter.Fill(objdataset);
        Dv.Table = objdataset.Tables[0];
        Dv.RowFilter = " name LIKE '%" + txtsearchgroup.Text + "%'";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Dv;
        objconnection.Close(); }
```

- txtsearchgroup : name of textbox for search word in datagridview1 and
- txtsearchgroup_KeyUp : event of keyup for search and filter word in datagridview1 and
- select name from groupitems : name is field for groupitems table and
- Dv.Table = objdataset.Tables[0] : zero (0) is first table in dataset