# search a DataGridView and then highlight the cell[s] in which the value is found?

Tags: c#, winforms, search, datagridview, full-text-search

I have a DataGridView that I'm feeding a List

The DataGridView is populating perfectly, but I'd like now to be able to search within the grid (any column) for a value the user enters.

I've been flailing about trying to sneak my way into a solution, but I can't find a DataGridView.Cells[X,Y] type of property.

I tried this:

```
String searchVal = textBoxValueToFindInGrid.Text.Trim();
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewPlatypusElements.RowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridViewPlatypusElements.ColumnCount; j++) {
        if (dataGridViewPlatypusElements.Text.Contains(searchVal))
        {
            dataGridViewPlatypusElements.GoTo*(Cells[j,i]);
        }
    }
}
```

...but, of course, DataGridView.Text does not contain anything useful. This is where I need the Cells[X,Y] property.

- I would not consider it harmful in this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210781/search-in-datagridview-c-sharp-winfom

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange Thanks, didn't see the tag

Comment: @Micah: I don't think that applies to my situation, using a List<MyClass> as a source of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
dataGridView.Rows[X].Cells[Y].Value
```

Comment: Brooklynhouse: How can I then select that cell, once finding a match, or those cells, on finding matches (might have to settle for one cell at a time)?

Answer (score 2):

May be useful for someother who has similar problem:

```
if(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString().Contains(searchText)
{
    dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Selected = true;
}
```

You can walk through the selected cells if you need more information about the cells:

```
foreach(DataGridViewCell selectedCell in dataGridView.SelectedCells)
{
    ..........
}
```